# Exclude vs filter, when using Q objects

Tags: python, django

Can't understand how this is possible:

```
A = object_list.filter( Q(sales__sale_starts__lte=today) & Q(sales__sale_ends__gte=today) )
# query inside filter catches 2 objects

B = object_list.exclude( Q(sales__sale_starts__lte=today) & Q(sales__sale_ends__gte=today) )
# query inside exclude catches 3 objects,
# though it is the same as previous

# in other words: object_list contains 20 objects,
# A - 2 objects, and B - 17 objects
```

Is there any difference in how `filter()` and `exclude()` working when using `Q` objects? Thanks.

I expect `B` to be as in:

```
B = object_list.difference(A)
# B contains 18 objects
```

Comment: What are the dates of the object that isn't captured? Are nulls allowed?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida dates can be null, **filter()** is working right filtering 2 objects, but **exclude()** is excluding 3 objects, though they have same queries

Comment: You didn't answer the other question, what are the dates of the additional object that is excluded?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida this excluded object has 2 related sales objects, 1:[01.01.2018 - 31.01.2018] 2:[01.06.2018 - 01.07.2018] [sale_starts - sale_ends]

Comment: The multi-valued result may be the issue, see these two bug reports: [Exclude query with multiple conditions for the same multi-value relation not correct](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14645); [Problem with negating Q object](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PauloAlmeida said

> The multi-valued result may be the issue, see these two bug reports:  [Exclude query with multiple conditions for the same multi-value relation not correct;](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14645) [Problem with negating Q object.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22709)

So there is indeed can be a difference between `filter()` and `exclude()`, because of different sql generation. And maybe bugs in `exclude()`.

Comment: There's a [note about this in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships), it's important to note it's not just for `Q` objects.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior should be the same. If you look at `.exclude()` and `.filter()` source code, they do the same:

```
def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a new QuerySet instance with NOT (args) ANDed to the existing
    set.
    """
    return self._filter_or_exclude(True, *args, **kwargs)

def filter(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Returns a new QuerySet instance with the args ANDed to the existing
    set.
    """
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
```

And `_filter_or_exclude()` just negate your `Q` filter with `~`

```
def _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs):
    if args or kwargs:
        assert self.query.can_filter(), \
            "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."

    clone = self._clone()
    if negate:
        clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
    else:
        clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    return clone
```