# Django, JSONField, filter for non empty list

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a jsonfield

```py
foo = JSONField(default=list)
```

I want to filter queryset so that foo has some data (not empty list)

I've tried

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(foo__ne=[])  # doesn't seem to work
MyModel.objects.filter(foo__gt=[])  # seems to work but can't be sure if it's the right approach
```

Answer (score 5):

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(foo=[]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to test inequality by negating equality using `Q` objects.

```py
from django.db.models import Q

MyModel.objects.filter(~Q(foo=[]))
```

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to `MyModel.objects.exclude(foo=[])`, right? See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246637/4709400